# How to get ImageBuffer correctly in Swift now with CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer?

Tags: ios, ios12, cmsamplebuffer

[image]

> 'CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer' has been replaced by property
>   'CMSampleBuffer.imageBuffer'

CMSampleBufferGet.ImageBuffer doesn't work :) It seems parameters also being changed regarding to Swift 4.2.

```
guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
```

Entire function. Just in case ...

```
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
//        print("Camera was able to capture a frame:", Date())

        guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: ARS().model) else { return }
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (finishedReq, err) in

            guard let results = finishedReq.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { return }
            guard let firstObservation = results.first else { return }

            print(firstObservation.identifier, firstObservation.confidence)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.identifierLabel.text = "\(firstObservation.identifier) \(firstObservation.confidence * 100)"
            }

        }

        try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])
    }
```

Did anyone try to solve this or has a reference for the new syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    let imageBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = sampleBuffer.imageBuffer!
    let ciimage : CIImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
    let image : UIImage = self.convert(cmage: ciimage)

}


// Convert CIImage to CGImage
func convert(cmage:CIImage) -> UIImage {
    let context:CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
    let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(cmage, from: cmage.extent)!
    let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    return image
}
```